# Creating a Sticky Navigation Bar Under a Logo Without the Use of External Libraries

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title implies, I have every intention of creating a web page that has a large logo above a navigation bar. This navigation bar will move up as the page is scrolled down until it locks in place at the top of the screen. I would then like a smaller logo to appear below the navigation bar and stay locked in place as well. I have searched four days for a solution on this webpage and other places to no prevail. More often than not the solution given involves downloading jquery libraries or bootstrap libraries. I do not wish to have either used for this if possible. The reason for this is because I am creating this web page as a learning experience, and having code held in other places will leave out portions that will confuse me at this time. So basically I want to know how it works, and not get the simple copy-paste method that has a library do all the work.

Here is what I have thusfar, and it was based entirely on this example: http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Den</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <table bordercolor="FD0000" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-color: FD0000; border-width:2px; border-top-style:solid; border-right-style:solid; border-bottom-style:solid; border-left-style:solid;">
<tr><td><center><a href="http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/"><img src="http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b494/ShadowfangInnovia/WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png" height="auto" width="940" border="0" alt=" photo WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png"/></a>
</center></td></tr></table>
</header>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <h2>Random words to fill in the gap.</h2>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>
    <p>Random words to fill in the gap.</p>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
header {
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #f07057;
}
.main-nav,
.main {
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 150;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
header,
.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.main {
  background: #f2f2e8;
  padding: 110px 50px 50px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var  mn = $(".main-nav");
    mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
    hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

The issue I have with the above example is that it only seems to work on the codepen page. The moment I take it off the website and save it to a notepad++ document and open it, suddenly the navigation bar scrolls past its intended point and off screen entirely. This is the same issue I have run into with every other tutorial I have come across. Either the navigation bar fails to stay on screen, or the logo will become a background that the text scrolls past, leaving the navigation bar stuck about 3/4 the way up the logo.

Comment: It would help if you supplied style.css and script.js. Also why exactly do you wish to avoid using libraries? They really can make things like this quite trivial...

Comment: Honestly it's because I'm extremely new to this and I'd like to see how it is functioning to understand it better. If some of the code is hosted elsewhere it's like a missing puzzle piece or two and it's just throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is without having to link elsewhere.**

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 290) {
            $('nav.main-nav').addClass('stickytop');
        }
        else {
            $('nav.main-nav').removeClass('stickytop');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font:16px/1.5 'Raleway',Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
 
h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:700
}
 
span {
    color:#27ae60;
    font-weight:700
}
 
h2 {
    font-size:35px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-20px
}
 
nav.demo-nav {
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block
}
 
nav.demo-nav a {
    font-size:19px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    color:#27ae60;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:5px 15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-radius:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:2px solid #ecf0f1;
    border-radius:none
}
 
nav a.active,nav a:hover {
    background:#ecf0f1;
    color:#27ae60
}

header {
    height:250px;
    background:#2ecc71;
    padding:23px 0
}
 
nav.main-nav {
    background:#fff;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
    text-align: center;
}
 
nav.main-nav a {
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 19px;
    color:#27ae60;
}
 
.container {
    display: inline;
    margin:0 auto;
}

nav.main-nav.stickytop {
    position:fixed;
    top:0
}

.content {
    color:#222;
    padding:50px;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:3;
/* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap:40;
    column-gap:40px;
}
 
.content h2 {
    margin:0;
}


@media all and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        padding:5px 0 55px;
    }
 
    nav.main-nav a {
        font-size:17px;
    }
 
    nav.main-nav {
        height:55px;
    }
 
    .container {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:50%;
 
    }
 
    .content {
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count:1;
        /* Firefox */
        column-count:1;
    }
}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        padding:5px 0 55px;
    }
 
    nav.main-nav a {
        font-size:17px;
    }
 
    nav.main-nav {
        height:55px;
    }
 
    .container {
        width:92%;
    }
 
    .content {
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count:1;
        /* Firefox */
        column-count:1
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<h1>Creating <span>Sticky</span> Navigation</h1>
<nav class="demo-nav">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Using jQuery</a>
        <a href="index2.html" >Using CSS</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="container">
 <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="content">
<h2>Main Content Here!</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote yet, but this answer helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article by CSS tricks on this subject; https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/ It's my go-to example after having done this a few times myself.

This code example also works great:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">

<header class="top-header">
    <span class="menu-icon">☰</span>
  </header>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search or type URL" />
  </div>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="hero"></div>
  </div>

  <main>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </main>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 480px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.top-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  .menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 18px 20px;
  }
  .fix-search & {
    background: #eee;
  }
}

.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  input {
    width: 265px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: width 0.2s;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
  .fix-search & {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    input {
      width: 250px;
    }
  }
}

.top {
  height: 250px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.hero {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  div {
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var wrap = $("#wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 147) {
    wrap.addClass("fix-search");
  } else {
    wrap.removeClass("fix-search");
  }

});
```

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/AdaKr

Comment: That is one of many links I had already visited. What ended up happening after adding my logo was that anytime I scrolled down far enough, the search bar (replaced with navigation bar) would lodge itself into my logo instead of the logo smoothly scrolling off screen. I notice this link also points to using JQuery which I would like to keep from using if possible. My goal is to build this with baseline HTML, CSS, and Javascript without any additional libraries.

Comment: I just tested it once more. The moment the logo gets added to replace the header icon in the example the code just falls apart. Perhaps it's the involvement of a table with my logo as it has a border built using table properties. Regardless, the bar gets lodged in there and the logo turns into more of a background than an actual header.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<header class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll, using jQuery</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves.</p>
  <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled passed the header element.</p>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* affix the navbar after scroll below header */
    $(".navbar").affix({offset: {top: $("header").outerHeight(true)} });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one is doing the trick, however is there a way to do it without the involvement of libraries? My goal is to have all my HTML, CSS, and JS hosted myself. I'm not particularly worried if there's a lot of javascript involved in making the process. I just want to make the process happen without having to link elsewhere.

Comment: @Shadowfang I'll do it

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at the edited post and seeing what you can do with it? The second example you posted also has a reference to JQuery as a script source. I'm doing my best to avoid that for the time being as explained above.

Comment: @Shadowfang jQuery is required for do sticky

Comment: Thank you for that. I managed to get your second example to work too.

Comment: Done. Thank you again. One final question though. Would you have any idea why other examples would work on codepen but not outside of it? Copying everything character for character to have completely different results seems bizarre.

Comment: @Shadowfang Maybe there is issue with including JS or CSS